LLC Half Bridge, Magnetic components testing and implementing problem
In my power supply design I am tested switching operations of half bridge circuit with open circuit and observed clear 155, -155 square wave I want to test step by step so for next step I want to implement to circuit a own build magnetic components (resonant inductor and transformer). Since this is my first time doing magnetic component I don't know how circuit behaves to magnetics. For example I try the test transformer with connect to 50 Hz variac primary of my transformer and give little bit AC signal I see current is getting higher and higher when I increase input voltage via variac and vibration noise is increasing with it (I guess its because of transformer is gapped and gaps is not very tight). With this test I can't observe if my winding ratios are good or not because input voltage can't observe since primer is like short circuited. I am stuck there. Any recommendation?
Firstly transformer is 3c94 ferroxcube ETD54 material. 21 primary turn and 11 secondary turns transformer is center tapped 3 winding. I give 0.75 gap with tape.
50kHz-150kHz working frequency. 75kHz resonant frequency
65 uH desired Lm (mutual inductance).
I found LCR meter from friend and trying to test measure inductances:
Primary Side inductance (secondary opened): 153 uH.
Secondary 1 inductance:47 uH.
Secondary 2 inductance:47 uH.
I don't quite understand it looks like wrong. I will send picture of how i wind the bobin maybe I did mistakes.
Winding structure, 2 layers inside of bobin is secondarys. Outside is primary.



Please state inductor and transformer core cross section area, material and number of turns.

@winny I editted post. Thanks.

And your switch frequency?


I am stuck there. Any recommendation?

The simple answer is get an LCR meter. Mine cost around £150 from Farnell and I would not be without it when winding my own transformers (which I do a few times a year). This is what I use and I'm very happy with it: -

Image from Farnell. If you are serious about designing this type of converter, you have to get the right equipment or else you'll never really get a grip to what your leakage inductance is and you'll be left scratching your head for hours and hours so, how much do you value your time?

In LCR meter how much henries this devices can measure sir. I take a look datasheet only see levels like 2mH/20mH etc. For example can I measure 20uH with 2mH level of LCR. I was think I can't measure thats why I am searching for good devices and they are not effordable.

@MSB page 12 of the data sheet says it can measure 20 uH with a resolution of 1 nH using the 100 kHz test frequency. Page 12 gives you all the ranges.

@MSB if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Hello, I am actually using LCR with your recommendation. But I don't quite understand why measurements are not right. Since the ratio of transformer is 21:11:11. Primer:Seconder1: Seconder2. Aren't the inductances should match this ratio

I share winding structure and I am trying New winding strategy, s1:P1:S2:P2. With 2 primary because of the wires having a hard time to fitting. I will share results after I finish. Trying new structure because my other structure dosnt looks right to me but maybe I am missing some point

@MSB please start a new post for your new question detailed in your recent two comments. It's advantageous to do so because it opens up your new question to the whole floor. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification. Note that inductance is proportional to turns ratio squared (when turns are closely coupled).
